# SQL query for cumulative sum of purchases across category

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

[image]

Write SQL query to get the cumulative sum of purchases across each category.
(Cumulative sum should be calculated following the order of purchases)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the cumulative sum function, which uses a window frame:

```
sum(purchases) over (partition by category order by order_date)
```

Comment: I tried this in mysql , but throwing syntacs exception.  Won't it work in all mysql versions? - SELECT item,category,purchases,order_date,SUM(purchases) OVER(PARTITION BY category order by order_date) AS cumulative_sum FROM orders;

Comment: @user2349253 . . . It works for MySQL 8+ which was released over three years ago.  In addition, this is Standard SQL and your question doesn't have a database tag.

Comment: Thank you . I will check my mysql version. Database being : test_db and table = orders